# Cannot open .docx or .xlsx files in iOS 7 SDK, still working fine with others like .doc, .xls, .rtf, .txt etc file format

Tags: iphone, excel, ios7, ms-word

I want to open .docx and .xlsx files (newer version of Ms-Word after office 2007). I had already tried with loading files with path on `UIWebView` and `QLPreviewController` in `iOS SDK`. These frameworks works with .xls, .doc, .txt, .rtf, all Image file formate and audio and video file formates but cannot open file of format .docx, xlsx.

How can I achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't support it out of the box. You will need to use a library; a typically used one is [libopc](http://libopc.codeplex.com/documentation)